# How to compare two or more field values

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation, splunk-sdk

i have this kind of data:

event 1:
field_name=field_value, status="process", status_file="file_name"

event 2:
field_name=field_value, status="send", status_file="file_name"

event 3:
field_name=field_value, transfer_status="transferred", transfer_file="file_name"

event 4: 
field_name=field_value, fatal_type1 = "reason1", fatal_type1_file="file_name"

event 5:
field_name=field_value, fatal_type2 = "reason2", fatal_type2_file="file_name"

from above all of the events common value is file_name rest of them are different. If the file_name matches with other file_types, it should list all I wanted make a report as below

file_name,     file_types, file_types_count

abfskjsfjskjjv, {process,send,transferred, reason2}, 4

hrhashlahsf,{process, reason1}, 2

fhkawuruhshfhuaf,{process, send, transferred}, 3